# Find suitable Constructor with reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, system.reflection

I am having some reflection issues, when finding the right constructor depending on the passed parameters.

So far this piece of code works fine, when the constructor arguments that are passed are not `null`:

```
public static ConstructorInfo? FindSuitableConstructor(Type typeWithConstructorToFind, object?[] constructorArguments)
{
    return typeWithConstructorToFind.GetConstructor(
            constructorArguments.Select(constructorArgumentInstance => constructorArgumentInstance.GetType())
            .ToArray());
}
```

But as soon as there is `null` involved it crashes as it can not call `GetType()` on `null`.

What are the alternatives to find the suitable constructor? I was thinking also of checking the numbers of arguments and also the parameter types (but again, it does not work on `null`) but so far not closer to what I am looking for.

I know that `Activator.CreateInstance(typeWithConstructorToFind, constructorArguments)` can find the right constructor somehow, but I don't need the instace of that type, I really need the `ConstructorInfo`.

Comment: Change `onstructorArgumentInstance.GetType()` to `onstructorArgumentInstance?.GetType() ?? typeof(object)`?

Comment: Even `Activator.CreateInstance` would throw `AmbiguousMatchException`, you know.

Comment: What do you need? Constructor without paramter?

Comment: Don't see that working when you not explicitly name the type. If you have 2 constructors one with a Foo parameter and another with a Bar parameter both references types and you hand over just null which one should be chosen?

Comment: Is your question about null checking? ```constructorArguments.Where(x =>x != null).Select(...)```

Comment: No ... Is about passing null to constructor .. reading with understanding is not easy  to find skill this days

Comment: My question is not about the null checking - It is finding the right constructor based on the given arguments. `Activator.CreateInstance` will choose the right one (unless `AmbiguousMatchException`) even when `null` is provided. `constructorArgumentInstance?.GetType() ?? typeof(object)` does not return a `ConstructorInfo` when typeof(object) is passed and the actual type is `System.String` for example.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/rttype.cs,5219 ... Activator.CreateInstance is itereting all constructors and trying to match

Comment: @Selvin the complexity he needs to replicate is mostly hidden in [DefaultBinder.BindToMethod](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/defaultbinder.cs,0ce742d2f09f660f,references)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [Binder.BindToMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.binder.bindtomethod?view=net-7.0):

```
public static ConstructorInfo? FindSuitableConstructor(Type typeWithConstructorToFind, object[] constructorArguments) {
    if (constructorArguments == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("constructorArguments");
    var constructors = typeWithConstructorToFind.GetConstructors();
    var argsCopy = constructorArguments.ToArray();
    try {
        return (ConstructorInfo)Type.DefaultBinder.BindToMethod(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, constructors, ref argsCopy, null, null, null, out _);
    }
    catch (MissingMemberException) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It will select the best match among a set of methods (in this case constructors) according to passed arguments. It's better than trying to do that yourself, because there are subtle cases. Note that it will not necessary fail if there are several constructors which match your arguments. For example:

```
public class Test {
    public Test(long x, string y) {

    }

    public Test(long x, object y) {

    }
}
```

If we try:

```
FindSuitableConstructor(typeof(Test), new object[] { 1, null });
```

which in theory matches both, it will return first constructor with `string` argument, because indeed you can do:

```
new Test(1, null);
```

And compiler will choose the `string` overload. However if you have for example this:

```
public class Test {
    public Test(long x, string y) {

    }

    public Test(long x, MethodInfo y) {

    }
}
```

Then the same will fail with `AmbiguousMatchException`, because indeed it's not possible to choose (and `new Test(1, null)` will not compile in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a build in method to allow achieve this. But you can an always try finding constructor manually. Something to start with:

```cs
var objects = new object?[] { 1, null };
if (objects.All(o => o is not null))
{
    return ..; // use current solution
}

var types = objects.Select(o => o?.GetType()).ToArray();
ConstructorInfo? candidate = null;
foreach (var constructorInfo in typeWithConstructorToFind.GetConstructors())
{
    var @params = constructorInfo.GetParameters();
    if (@params.Length != types.Length)
    {
        continue;
    }

    for (var index = 0; index < @params.Length; index++)
    {
        var parameterInfo = @params[index];
        var type = types[index];
        if ((type == null && !parameterInfo.ParameterType.IsValueType) || parameterInfo.ParameterType.IsAssignableFrom(type)) // todo - check for explicit casts
        {
            continue; // can pass null or type matches - continue params check
        }
        break;
    }
    
    // all params satisfy 
    if (candidate is null)
    {
        candidate = constructorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new AmbiguousMatchException();
    }
}    

return candidate;
```

Comment: I tried also this solution, it is also working (only the `return candidate;` statement at the end is missing. ) - Anyhow I prefer the less complex answer provider by @Evk

Comment: @DominikAmon note that this answer and `Binder.BindToMethod` will disagree in MANY cases, so they are not the same. Even for example provided in my answer - constructors accept `long` as first parameter but I pass "1" which is int32 everywhere. This approach will not find any matches because `IsAssignableFrom` will not work for `long` and `int`.

Comment: @Evk JIC - in one of precious modifications added todo comment to answer regarding this case =)